# In a PHP foreach, which is faster, negating condition or continuing?

Tags: php, foreach, continue

Consider the following code:

```
foreach ($products as $product) {
    if (some_long_condition()) {
        continue;
    } 
    do_stuff();
```

Which would be faster, having a condition with a `continue`, or negating the condition itself? Is there a difference at all in terms of performance, or is it just syntactic sugar?

Comment: I would say, negating will be better. Gut feeling.

Comment: Bench. Mark. It. The actual performance may depend on the specifics of your situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly the same, a boolean comparison. The compiler doesn't make a difference here.